# How do I document methods where providing a block is optional?

Tags: ruby, rdoc, yard

I have a function documented like this:

```
##
# Searches for street names in the local address database. Returns a list
# of strings, or invokes the block for each result.
#
# @param [String, Hash] query
#
#   Can be:
#
#   - A search string with optinal wildcards. Examples:
#     - "Bærumsv*"
#     - "Fornebuve_en"
#
# @param [Integer] limit
#
#   Limits the amount of results. See {#search_street_addresses} for usage
#   examples.
#
# @return [Array<String>]
#
#   A sorted array of street names.
#
# @yield [street_name] Invokes the block with a street name for each
#   result.
#
```

Yielding this result:

[image: Screenshot]

My issue is that the documentation says that the function expects a block and that it returns a value. In reality, the block is optional. If the block is provided, it is invoked for each result and the function returns nothing (`nil`). If no block is provided, the results are returned in an Array.

How do I make this clear in the documentation? Is there a recommended way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `@overload`

```
##
# Searches for street names in the local address database. Returns a list
# of strings, or invokes the block for each result.
#@overload search_street_names(query, limit: nil)
#  @param [String, Hash] query
#
#    Can be:
#
#    - A search string with optinal wildcards. Examples:
#      - "Bærumsv*"
#      - "Fornebuve_en"
#
#  @param [Integer] limit
#
#    Limits the amount of results. See {#search_street_addresses} for usage
#    examples.
#
#  @return [Array<String>]
#
#    A sorted array of street names.
#
#@overload search_street_names(query, limit: nil)
#  @param [String, Hash] query
#
#    Can be:
#
#    - A search string with optinal wildcards. Examples:
#      - "Bærumsv*"
#      - "Fornebuve_en"
#
#  @param [Integer] limit
#
#    Limits the amount of results. See {#search_street_addresses} for usage
#    examples.
#
#  @yield [street_name] Invokes the block with a street name for each
#    result.
##
```

Returns:

[image]

Comment: I never expected that the answer could be this perfect <3

Comment: :) Thank you for the compliment.